# How to use the same target group of instances with 2 ELBs (ALBs) + auto-scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I'm trying to route some traffic to one target group from two ELBs (ALBs). One is external & the other one is an internal one.

I have the following rules in my external ALB:

```
IF path is /static/* THEN forward to frontends
IF path is /media/* THEN forward to frontends
```

An internal ALB has to direct it's traffic to the same target group 'frontends', but the group is grayed out & can't be selected :(

As a workaround I've created another target group 'frontends2' & selected it on the internal ALB.

But we're preparing for autoscaling so having 2 separate target groups for the same group of instances is not convenient.

I'm using AWS web console for configuration. Is it possible to achieve my goal through it(same target group, different ALBs) or do I have to use CLI?

P.S. btw will it be the same with autoscaling groups? We're planning to autoscale a group of instances based on parameters like cpu load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A target group can only be associated with a single load balancer, and that's a hard limit they won't raise, setting it up through the CLI or console won't make a difference.  However, you can associate both of your two target groups with 1 AutoScaling Group.  That way whenever it launches/terminates an instance they will be registered/deregistered with both  target groups.

> Target Group Limits
>
> Load balancers per target group: 1

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-limits.html